# get selected category using radiobuttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selecteditem, radiobuttonlist

I have a problem where I'm not sure whether I'm using the right logic for the purpose.

What I am trying to achieve is to create a radionbuttonlist (Categories) for each categories in my db. When user select a radionbutton, the Booklist should be updated appropriately using the categoryID.

i.e. from my categorytable I get rendered, sci fi and romantic, when user select a category the booklist only show the books with the matching categoryID

My ViewModel stores two 'Lists' which I can iterate over in the View.

ViewModel:

```
public class SortBookVM
{
    public IEnumerable<Book> BookList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> CategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

In the Controller I want add the logic between those to list.

**Is that correct and if so how do I implement it here? or should the logic be elsewhere?**

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetBook(int? groupID)
{
    HowEntities db = new HowEntities();
    SortBookVM sbVM = new SortBookVM();

    sbVM.ClassList = db.Book.ToList<Book>();
    sbVM.CardList = db.Category.ToList<Category>();

    //Book b = new Book();
    //var query = from x in db.Book where c.CategorypID == groupID select x;

    return View(sbVM );
}
```

Here I'm looping through the 'Lists' to get all the data.

View:

```
@foreach (var v in Model.CategoryList)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => v.CategoryName)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => v.ID, true)
}
@foreach (var item in Model.BookList)
{
    <li>
         @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Name)
    </li>
}
```

So what I am asking is my logic how to achieve this correct and if so how do I proceed from here? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't seem to have much of a *logic* right now in your controller. You only instantiate the `sbVM` view model and pass it to the view. You seem to be working with some `svHm` variable which is unclear where is it coming from nor what happens with it later. But you never set the 2 List properties on the view model that gets passed to your view. So your view is likely to crash pretty badly.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do this.  I would use some jquery that fires off an event on radio button select.  Then make the book list a sub-view that takes a category input and displays the correct books.  You need to have some sort of listener for the radio buttons.

Comment: sry the svHm is the sbVM ofc, typo from my side.. Yes by logic i mean this a proper architecthture or what to call it.
and yes i want to use some kind of jquery when i get more comforteble with mvc in genrel.. But it is exactly the listener im confused about? how do i get them to repond to som logic in the controller?